# jqgrid group header not showing ampersand character in IE 7/8

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am using jqgrid to show dynamic data in it, my sql stored procedure returns some data as "T & E". I am displaying this data in group header, i can only see "T" in the group header the rest of the data is trimmed down in IE 7/8. The same thing when i run it in Firefox it show correctly as "T & E". Please tell me the solution for this problem, any help would be appreciated.

I have tried the autoencode property setting it to true, but it did not work,
I have kept the meta tag character encoding utf-8 in the aspx file.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue while editing . This [link](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/02/08/38548/) helped me to attain what i wanted with some tweaks.

My system config.

Win 7 with IE8

While editing, the text after the '&' was lost. Eg: If we had text like 'a&a' only 'a' used to show up in the grid and get saved eventually.

The custom formatter how ever did the trick for me.

```
//In col Model 
//Assuming description is one of your column in the jqGrid
//Note the formatter , this is the custom formatter which does the magic for us in this case.
{ name: 'Description', index: 'Description', align: "center", sorttype: 'text', sortable: true, resizable: false, editable: editGrids, formatter: formatTextDisplay,unformat:unformatTextDisplay}

//Formatter code
var formatTextDisplay = function (cellval, opts, action) {
            if (cellval) {
                return $.jgrid.htmlEncode(cellval);
            };
            return "";
        }

//Un formatter code, in case you want to read through the text in its original state from the grid for processing in the javascript file.
var unformatTextDisplay = function (cellval, opts, action) {
            if (cellval) {
                return $.jgrid.htmlDecode(cellval);
            };
            return "";
        }
```